# Python3 with sql variables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select

Hello I'm currently working with python. I have a file that selects data from a database through a query. But I want to select the data filtered on the timestamp. I can select all the data(with the simple select ... from *table* etc etc). But if I add the WHERE query in the whole query, the program will fail.

I hope anybody can help me.

This is my code so far:

```
import datetime
import time
import mysql.connector

ts = '2013-10-21 00:00:00'
f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

now = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts,f)
print (now)

time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (time.strftime)

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='**', password='**', host='**', database='*dbname*')
cursor = connection.cursor()

str_now = now.date().isoformat()

query = ("SELECT version, protocol, ttl, des_address, des_port, source_address, source_port, timestamp  FROM *tablename* **WHERE timestamp = %s", (str_now))** 

cursor.execute(query)

for (version, protocol, ttl, des_address, des_port, source_address, source_port, timestamp) in cursor:
      print("Version:"+str(version),"Protocol:" + str(protocol), 
      "TTL:" + str(ttl), "Destination Address:" + str(des_address), 
    "Destination Port:" + str(des_port), "Source Address:" + str(source_address), 
        "Source Port:" + str(source_port), "Timestamp:" + str(timestamp))

print (cursor.lastrowid)
```

If I run this code I will get the following error: "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' ".

When I search on Google I don't found a good answer.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to delimit your

```
WHERE timestamp = %s
```

like

```
WHERE timestamp = '%s'
```